# ember.js routing hierarchy

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I would like to have routing hierarchy.
So it would be nice if URLs "#/user/123" and "#/user/123/albums" will work.
And i want to do that this way:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  root: Em.Route.extend({
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    }),
    user: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/user/:login',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user', context);
      },
      albums: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/albums',
        connectOutlets: function(router){
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('albums');
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Not this way:

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
  root: Em.Route.extend({
    index: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/'
    }),
    user: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/user/:login',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('user', context);
      }
    }),
    albums: Em.Route.extend({
      route: '/user/:login/albums',
      connectOutlets: function(router){
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('albums');
      }
    })
  })
});
```

My first code examle sims to be silly, but i want to have routing hierarchy. Is there any ability to do that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is certainly doable. There are many examples out there of nested routes. I can't check your specific Router against an a real app, but there's an example very much long this lines in the [Ember Application Structure guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/). See the section on Nesting. You'll find this:

```
post: Ember.Route.extend({
  route: '/posts/:post_id',
  connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('post', post);
  },
  index: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    redirectsTo: 'comments'
  }),
  comments: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/comments',
    showTrackbacks: Ember.Route.transitionTo('trackbacks'),
    connectOutlets: function(router) {
      var postController = router.get('postController');
      postController.connectOutlet('comments', postController.get('comments'));
    }
  }),
  trackbacks: Ember.Route.extend({
    route: '/trackbacks',
    showComments: Ember.Route.transitionTo('comments'),
    connectOutlets: function(router) {
      var postController = router.get('postController');
      postController.connectOutlet('trackbacks', postController.get('trackbacks'));
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: +1, I confirm the first implementation of @user1753867 should work.